# Charts: Get selected bar data only when tapped inside the bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, bar-chart, ios-charts

I used the https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts library in my project.
It is working perfectly but I want to select bar data only when user taps inside the bar. Currently it will return bar data on outside the tap also. It is providing the nearest bar data to the tap when user tap outside the bar.

I set up the bar chart like this :

```
_chartView.delegate = self;

_chartView.drawBarShadowEnabled = NO;
_chartView.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = YES;

_chartView.maxVisibleValueCount = 60;

ChartXAxis *xAxis = _chartView.xAxis;
xAxis.labelPosition = XAxisLabelPositionBottom;
xAxis.labelTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
xAxis.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.f];
xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
xAxis.spaceBetweenLabels = 2.0;
xAxis.labelWidth = 100;

ChartYAxis *leftAxis = _chartView.leftAxis;
leftAxis.labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.f];
leftAxis.labelCount = 5;
leftAxis.labelTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
leftAxis.valueFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
leftAxis.valueFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1;
leftAxis.valueFormatter.negativeSuffix = @"k";
leftAxis.valueFormatter.positiveSuffix = @"k";
leftAxis.valueFormatter.positivePrefix = @"$";
leftAxis.valueFormatter.negativePrefix = @"$";
leftAxis.labelPosition = YAxisLabelPositionOutsideChart;
leftAxis.spaceTop = 0.15;
leftAxis.customAxisMin = 0.0; // this replaces startAtZero = YES


_chartView.legend.position = ChartLegendPositionBelowChartLeft;
_chartView.legend.form = ChartLegendFormSquare;
_chartView.legend.formSize = 20.0;
_chartView.legend.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20.f];
_chartView.legend.xEntrySpace = 4.0;
_chartView.legend.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


NSMutableArray *xVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    [xVals addObject:months[i % 12]];
}

NSMutableArray *yVals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *yValsColor = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


[yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:10 xIndex:1]];
[yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:15 xIndex:2]];
[yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:20 xIndex:3]];
[yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:45 xIndex:4]];
[yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:30 xIndex:5]];
[yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:5 xIndex:6]];
[yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:15 xIndex:7]];
[yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:22 xIndex:8]];
[yVals addObject:[[BarChartDataEntry alloc] initWithValue:32 xIndex:9]];

[yValsColor addObject:[UIColor yellowColor]];

BarChartDataSet *set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithYVals:yVals label:@"Charges"];
set1.barSpace = 0.35;
set1.colors     =  yValsColor;

NSMutableArray *dataSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[dataSets addObject:set1];

BarChartData *data = [[BarChartData alloc] initWithXVals:xVals dataSets:dataSets];
[data setValueFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20.f]];
[data setValueTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

_chartView.data = data;


NSArray *arrLabelData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"All", @"1/1/2016 to 9/29/2016", @"All", @"All", @"Date of Billed",nil];
NSArray *arrLabel     = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ins:",@" DOS:",@" Location:",@" Provider:",@" Aging Calculation Based On:",nil];


NSMutableAttributedString *strFS = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
UIColor *color = [UIColor yellowColor]; // select needed color

NSDictionary *attrs = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color};
NSDictionary *attrsLab = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};

for(int i = 0; i <arrLabelData.count; i++)
{
    NSString *strLabData = [arrLabelData objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *strLab     = [arrLabel objectAtIndex:i];
    
    NSAttributedString *attStringLab        = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strLab attributes:attrsLab];
    NSAttributedString *attStringLabData    = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:strLabData attributes:attrs];
    
    [strFS appendAttributedString:attStringLab];
    [strFS appendAttributedString:attStringLabData];
    
}
lblAttributes.attributedText = strFS;
```

I want to respond the data only when user tapped inside the bar.

Any one have idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have user version 2.2.3 of charts in my App. Try this implementation to resolve your issue

1) Add function to your **ChartHighlighter.swift** file.

```
public func getBarBounds(e: BarChartDataEntry) -> CGRect
{

    guard let
        set = self.chart?._data?.getDataSetForEntry(e) as? IBarChartDataSet
        else { return CGRectNull }

    let barspace = set.barSpace
    let y = CGFloat(e.value)
    let x = CGFloat(e.xIndex)

    let barWidth: CGFloat = 0.5

    let spaceHalf = barspace / 2.0
    let left = x - barWidth + spaceHalf
    let right = x + barWidth - spaceHalf
    let top = y >= 0.0 ? y : 0.0
    let bottom = y <= 0.0 ? y : 0.0

    var bounds = CGRect(x: left, y: top, width: right - left, height: bottom - top)

    self.chart?.getTransformer(ChartYAxis.AxisDependency.Left).rectValueToPixel(&bounds)

    return bounds
}
```

2) Update **getHighlight** function in **ChartHighlighter.swift** file.

```
public func getHighlight(x x: Double, y: Double) -> ChartHighlight?
{
    let xIndex = getXIndex(x)
    if (xIndex == -Int.max)
    {
        return nil
    }


    let dataSetIndex = getDataSetIndex(xIndex: xIndex, x: x, y: y)
    if (dataSetIndex == -Int.max)
    {
        return nil
    }

    //Modification for only Bar Selection
    let dataSet = self.chart!.data!.getDataSetByIndex(dataSetIndex)
    let e = dataSet.entryForXIndex(xIndex) as! BarChartDataEntry!
    let rectData = getBarBounds(e)

    let point = CGPoint(x: x,y: y)
    let isPointInFrame = CGRectContainsPoint(rectData, point)
    if (!isPointInFrame)
    {
        return nil
    }
    //Modification for only Bar Selection


    return ChartHighlight(xIndex: xIndex, dataSetIndex: dataSetIndex)
}
```

Hope it will help you. Happy Coding...

Comment: Wht if im using pods. I can't edit the souce code? ia sthere any other way ?

Comment: How to do same thing with version 3.0.4

Comment: hey.. I am getting nil here     let e = dataSet.entryForXIndex(xIndex) as! BarChartDataEntry!
i am using horizontalbarchart

Comment: i am always getting crash on this line             let entry = set?.entryForIndex(Int(high.y)) as! BarChartDataEntry

Answer (score 0):

I have a project with the same library and I was able to get the functionality you are asking for by changing the getHighlight function inside the ChartHighlighter.swift file to the following:

```
/// Returns a Highlight object corresponding to the given x- and y- touch positions in pixels.
/// - parameter x:
/// - parameter y:
/// - returns:
public func getHighlight(x x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> ChartHighlight?
{
    print("y: \(y)")
    let xIndex = getXIndex(x)

    guard let
        selectionDetail = getSelectionDetail(xIndex: xIndex, y: y, dataSetIndex: nil)
        else { return nil }
    print("selectionDetail: \(selectionDetail.y)")
    if(y<selectionDetail.y) {
        return nil
    }
    else {
        return ChartHighlight(xIndex: xIndex, value: selectionDetail.value, dataIndex: selectionDetail.dataIndex, dataSetIndex: selectionDetail.dataSetIndex, stackIndex: -1)
    }
}
```

Comment: I not found getSelectionDetail function in my library

Comment: I am using version 2.2.5, maybe you have a different version

Answer (score 0):

I converted @rohit Sidpara's answer for 3.2.1 version of Charts

Both functions need to be written at BarHighlighter.swift file

```
open override func getHighlight(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> Highlight?
{
    guard
        let barData = (self.chart as? BarChartDataProvider)?.barData,
        let high = super.getHighlight(x: x, y: y)
        else { return nil }

    let pos = getValsForTouch(x: x, y: y)

    if let set = barData.getDataSetByIndex(high.dataSetIndex) as? IBarChartDataSet,
        set.isStacked
    {
        return getStackedHighlight(high: high,
                                   set: set,
                                   xValue: Double(pos.x),
                                   yValue: Double(pos.y))
    }
    else
    {
        let set = barData.getDataSetByIndex(high.dataSetIndex) as? IBarChartDataSet
        let entry = set?.entryForIndex(Int(high.x)) as! BarChartDataEntry
        let rectOfData = getBarBounds(e: entry)

        return rectOfData.contains(CGPoint(x: x, y: y)) ? high: nil
    }
}

public func getBarBounds(e: BarChartDataEntry) -> CGRect
{

    guard
        let dataProvider = self.chart as? BarChartDataProvider
        else { return CGRect.null }

    let barspace = CGFloat((dataProvider.barData?.barWidth)!) / 2.0
    let y = CGFloat(e.y)
    let x = CGFloat(e.x)

    let barWidth: CGFloat = 0.5

    let spaceHalf = barspace / 2.0
    let left = x - barWidth + spaceHalf
    let right = x + barWidth - spaceHalf
    let top = y >= 0.0 ? y : 0.0
    let bottom = y <= 0.0 ? y : 0.0

    var bounds = CGRect(x: left, y: top, width: right - left, height: bottom - top)

    dataProvider.getTransformer(forAxis: YAxis.AxisDependency.left).rectValueToPixel(&bounds)

    return bounds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Tap to this link: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/ChartsDemo-iOS/Objective-C/Components/BalloonMarker.swift
2. Copy all and paste to your project
3. Add

   ```swift
   myBarChart.delegate = self
   myBarChart.legend.enabled = false
   ```
4. Use it

   ```swift
   extension StatisticUsageChartView: ChartViewDelegate {
       func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
           let marker: BalloonMarker = BalloonMarker(color: Colors._9e9e9e.color,
                                                     font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10),
                                                     textColor: .white,
                                                     insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 5.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 7.0, right: 5.0))
           marker.isPercent = self.isPercent
           marker.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(50, 35)
           chartView.marker = marker

           self.myBarChart.centerViewToAnimated(xValue: entry.x, 
                                                yValue: entry.y,
                                                axis: self.myBarChart.data![highlight.dataSetIndex].axisDependency,
                                                                duration: 0.7)
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Maximum hightlightdistance property is available for chartview default is 500 dp. Change it to 10 and check you're view